# Most efficient way to run query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo, php-5.5

Since PHP5 and with the delete of mysql_query (RIP.) I'm quite confused on what the most effecient way to run a query. Since there are multiple ways.

The options that I know of are these:

Option 1:

```
$getInfo = "SELECT * FROM app2 WHERE id='". $appID ."' ";
$oStmt = $dbportal->prepare($getInfo);
$oStmt = $dbportal->execute();
```

I believe this is PDO.

Option 2:

```
$createQuery="INSERT INTO usr2 SET login='". $user ."', role='". $role ."'";
$dbportal->query($createQuery);
```

kinda PDOish?

Would someone be so kinda to push me in the right direction? A link is fine too, couldn't find anything

OfficialBAMM. \o/

Comment: Those are incredibly terrible ways of running queries since you are still using string interpolation which is as vulnerable as `mysql_query` would be. Go through this and you'll find much better ways http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?s=1|22.9210

Comment: @Hanky, thanks. The unedited answer wasn't very helpfull >.<

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prevent SQL injection, you should use prepared statements with placeholders:

```
$getInfo = "SELECT * FROM app2 WHERE id = :id";
$oStmt = $dbportal->prepare($getInfo);
$oStmt->execute(array(':id' => $appID));
```

Efficiency should not be a concern until you get the code correct. Premature optimization is the root of all evil. And the slow part of performing a database query is accessing the data, not the way you call it.

Comment: I am not sure, what does the PO mean by the word "efficient"? The fastest? But prepared statements are almost as fast as primitive `query()` calls. Cause you'll need to escape the suspicious variables anyway.

Comment: Who cares what he means by it? The bottleneck is almost certainly going o be in searching the database, not the form of the query.

Comment: @barmar if I have a query without user input, is it okay not to use PDO?

Comment: It's still a good idea to use placeholders, you don't have to worry about special characters in the data.

Comment: Sorry, placeholders? I'm guessing `':id' => $appID`?

Comment: Placeholders are the `:xxx` in the query, e.g. `WHERE id = :id`. They get replaced with the parameters in the `execute()` array, or you can use `$oStmt->bindParam()` to bind them to variables.

Comment: This is all explained in the PDO documentation.

Comment: Okay thanks. I'll read the PDO doc instead of bothering you. Thanks for your help!